# How do I get Istio route matching to work?

Tags: istio

I have an Istio gateway, Istio VirtualService, and app deployed running as a service. The virtual service is deployed like so:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: my-app-route
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - my-gateway
  http:
    - match:
      - uri:
          prefix: "/my-app"
    route:
    - destination:
        host: my-app-service
        port:
          number: 8000
```

When I navigate to http://myurl.com/my-app I would expect to see a JSON response from the service it is pointing to, but I just get a 404. However if I remove the match and redeploy like so:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: my-app-route
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  http:
    - route:
      - destination:
          host: my-app-service
          port:
            number: 800
```

And then go to http://myurl.com/my-app I can see the expected JSON response. Any help?

Comment: the application you are serving, what is the entry path? `/` or `/my-app`, if it is a SPA the entry point can be `/` and then redirect to `/my-app`

Comment: It is not a SPA, the app is being served on ```/```. The ```/my-app``` route is an end point that another application can do a GET/POST on. Hitting the ```/``` route should go to the web UI.